# Numbers with large algebraic independency

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Define the measure of algebraic independence of the numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ as

$\Phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n; m, H) = \min |P(a_1, \ldots, a_n)|$,

where the minimum is taken over all polynomials of degree at most $m$, with integer coefficients not all of which are zero, and of magnitude at most $H$.

**Question:** 1) How large can be $\Phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n; m, H)$ for fixing $n, m, H$?7

2) What lower bounds of $\Phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n; m, H)$ are known for *explicit* $a_1, \ldots, a_n$?

( I want to find $a_1, \ldots a_n$ such that $\Phi$ is large.)

Comment: just to clarify: all $a_k$ are algebraic, I presume, and $n>1$ ? For $m=n=1$ this becomes the question about approximating $a_1$ by rational numbers...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik No, $a_k$ can be transcendental.

Comment: First question: for fixed $m$ and $H$ the obvious upper bound is 1. If you are interested in behavior for fixed a and increasing $H$ and $m$, then Dirichlet gives something like $(H/A)^{-m}$ where $A=\max a_i$. If you are interested in lower bounds, then even for $m=1$, $\Phi$ may be asymptotically smaller than any given positive function of $H$. It's debatable, but given the construction of such  bad $a_i$ is quite explicit.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin Maybe my question is not clear: I want to find $a_1, \ldots a_n$ such that $\Phi$ is large.

Comment: I see. You are interested in some analogue of badly approximated numbers.